# Filtering a Json::Value object on a keys value

Tags: c++11

I have an json object:   `[{a:"b"},{a:"c"},{a:"c"},{a:"d"},{a:"e"}]`
which is stored in a `Json::Value` object.

I seem to be having some trouble with filtering that JSON object down to say:  where only "a" = "c"

I was trying to do the following:

```
Json::Value data (*result.GetValue());
std::string filterValue = message->GetData()["Filter"];
std::string filterKey("a");
//above was just a quick variable definition for my example.

for ( auto row = data.begin(); row != data.end(); ++row )
    {
    if ( *row[filterKey].asString().compare(filterValue) != 0 )
        {
        //Remove this row from the JSON object.
        }
    }
```

Normally i am a Javascript dev, but i wanted to filter the results in C++11 before sending it to the client.  In Javascript it is just as simple as:  `[].filter(function(ele){ if (ele["a"] == "c") return true; return false; });` but that is no help here.

In the Json::Value api, i didnt see any sort of filtering functions.

EDIT:  The other issue is i was not sure how everything would act in the loop if i removed the item...  something like:   `row->clear()` or similar

Answer (score 0, accepted):

just do:

```
Json::Value newOut;
for (Json::Value row : data )
  {
  if (row["a"].asString().compare("b") == 0)
    {
    newOut.append(row);
    }
  }
return newOut;
```

That will return the subset which matches.  No need to do iterator in this case.